# Can I store half of a record on one page and half of the record on another page?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I'm watching Paul Randal's MCM video from http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/gg313756.aspx

From 27:11 of the video, the author said a record must be saved in one page, you can't have half of a record on one page and half of it on another page. This opinion is not what I learned. However I'm not confident about it, since I'm not an English native speaker and may misunderstood Paul's opinion. Anyone can help to explain a little?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are splitting hairs over semantics. A physical record cannot *span* pages. A physical record has to fit in a page.

*But* a index (or heap) row consists potentially from more than one physical records. An index row will consist from exactly one record in the IN_ROW_DATA allocation unit *and* zero, one or more records in ROW_OVEFLOW_DATA and/or LOB_DATA. The IN_ROW_DATA record contains pointers to overflow or LOB records. These off-row records themselves may contain more pointers to form a chain or a tree (this is how a `VARCHAR(MAX)` column can have  values that are obviously much larger than 8060 bytes). Such a large value will consist from many individual records, each of 8060 bytes or less. None of these record will ever span multiple pages.

And I did not even touch columnstore index rows, which are *completely* different.

Comment: Remus, if you have some good insights on columnstore feel free to add them [on this question](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/10411/whats-the-anatomy-of-a-columnstore-index)

Comment: What is a 'physical record'?

Comment: A 'record' is the thing described in [Anatomy of a Record](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/post/Inside-the-Storage-Engine-Anatomy-of-a-record.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

I think I found the answer. The following paragraph is from SQL Server documentation. Note the first sentence, **"Rows cannot span pages, however portions of the row may be moved off
the row's page so that the row can actually be very large"**. What I think is that if portions of the row may be moved off the row's page, it already means the row spanned pages, right?

> Rows cannot span pages, however portions of the row may be moved off
>   the row's page so that the row can actually be very large. The maximum
>   amount of data and overhead that is contained in a single row on a
>   page is 8,060 bytes (8 KB). However, this does not include the data
>   stored in the Text/Image page type. This restriction is relaxed for
>   tables that contain varchar, nvarchar, varbinary, or sql_variant
>   columns. When the total row size of all fixed and variable columns in
>   a table exceeds the 8,060 byte limitation, SQL Server dynamically
>   moves one or more variable length columns to pages in the
>   ROW_OVERFLOW_DATA allocation unit, starting with the column with the
>   largest width. This is done whenever an insert or update operation
>   increases the total size of the row beyond the 8060 byte limit. When a
>   column is moved to a page in the ROW_OVERFLOW_DATA allocation unit, a
>   24-byte pointer on the original page in the IN_ROW_DATA allocation
>   unit is maintained. If a subsequent operation reduces the row size,
>   SQL Server dynamically moves the columns back to the original data
>   page. For more information, see Row-Overflow Data Exceeding 8 KB.